# text cutting off when print preview page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to print some views with some div and text in it but for some reason when I try to print the page some of the text within the div cuts off, so basically I dont see the whole text.

This is a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media print {
    .flex-container {}
    .flex-container > div   { overflow: visible }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk  jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk fundi</div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting that when clicking print button would show the content in separate pages or somehow show a long div with full text and not cut off the text.

Any idea how can I fix this using css?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be worth exploring the `page-break-inside` CSS property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: try javascript `window.print()` function

Comment: nothing is working

Comment: It is not easy to help when your example is not actually showing the error. Try to create a demo of your problem, that actually behaves the same way as in your app. Actually, that way you might also get a deeper understanding of your problem and may enable you to fix it yourself. Also, the solution to not getting an answer is not to post a new that is a copy of the first one...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show all the content in a div when printing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721887/how-to-show-all-the-content-in-a-div-when-printing-the-page)