# How to show all the content in a div when printing the page

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a div which contains a long text and when printing the page I would like it so the whole text is being printed and not cut off the text.

I can provide some sample which is not my real case but it is very similiar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background:green;
  padding:10px
}

.flex-container > div {
 background:silver;
 padding:10px;
}



@media print  
{
    div{

    }
}

@page {

}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd
  1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd
  1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ad ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk  jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk fundi</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So when I call window.print() on button click or press ctrl+P I cannot see whole page showing on the print preview.

PROBLEM: Cutting off the text
EXPECTED RESULT: Whole content on the div

UPDATE: Screen Shot added for better explanation
[image]

As you can see the from the image above, some text is missing, I would like the div to expand and show the text on the second page and so on if there is more text.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You need to adapt your CSS in the @media print section so it stays within the page size. You have a section for it but haven't tried anything?

Comment: reduce font size to fit inside a div, And background color doesn't showup in print preview

Comment: @PrashanthReddy reducing font size is not a solution at all.

Comment: I don’t see anything in this example that would cut the text off when being printed (unless there’s something about flexbox having that problem in general, that I don’t know about) - can you verify that you get the same problem with this minimal example? And then, what kind of fix do you _need_ - can flexbox be overwritten with something else for printing (like a simple `display:block`), or do you need certain flexbox properties for the print output as well?

Comment: @JuanMendes I am asking why when Print Preview the text within the div cuts off, so u dont see the whole text in the div, so it dissapear some part of it. I dont know how else I can explain this to you!

Comment: To me, when I try your example and try to open the "Print Preview" it looks fine. The text flows over mulitple pages though...

Comment: @HelgeFox how come, what browser are you using? can u send a print screen

Comment: Here is a print screen of the Print Preview: https://i.imgur.com/AwuR7Uu.jpg

Comment: I use Google Chrome as my browser

Comment: @HelgeFox interesting, it actually shows quite right in ur browser, in my chrome browser it does not show that way, so probably problem with version of chrome. but thnx

Comment: @HelgeFox may I ask what version of chrome are u using? or do u have any idea why the text does not show in full for me?

Comment: Here is the thing, the same example preview print works fine if I wrap all this html code into a some html file and open it locally on my machine. if I run this for example here on this editor: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox and paste the above html code then the print preview doesnt work well, how is this possible?

Comment: my chrome is the newest one. Check this Demo: https://jsbin.com/gavuwij/edit?html,output

Comment: @HelgeFox is the print preview in the demo u showed working for you? I mean does the text shows full?

Comment: If you try to print the demo itself your browser will try to print *everything* including all elements of jsbin like menus and headers and stuff... As I guess happens on w3school as well. If you open "Live preview" it works: https://output.jsbin.com/gavuwij

Comment: @HelgeFox this is the issue I am actually facing, I have exactly same problem, where some text (very long) I am showing with a div in some web app and when trying print preview it does not show it full. So what do u think I can do in such case?

Comment: In your @media print you have to make the page look like you want when printing. For example you can hide the other elements, or let your content-div be `position: absolute` and make sure it spans the whole page. Depending on the actual circumstances of your app...

Comment: Here is a very generic example that shows the principle of using @media queries: https://output.jsbin.com/gavuwij

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last week. I experimented with the position, overflow and display properties and it solved my problem. You can give it a try.

```
 .flex-container {        
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;    
    display: block !important;    
    position: static;    
    overflow: unset!important;        
  }
```

Ok i remember some further details.
Besides the styling, i did a few hacks. Here it is:

1. When i click on the print link, i called a function to first copy contents of the printable division to some other division, lets say, '#print-div" (In my case, i copied the div because i needed to preserve the print view as it is. )
2. Then i hid everything else on the page and only made #print-div visible. (The styling i pasted earlier is meant for this print-div)
3. With only this div showing up at 100% width and height, you can call window.print(). This worked for me perfectly. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It doesnt work for me, still the text is not full showing... I am using Chrome just so u know!

Answer (score 0):

You could use css `@media` query like this:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background:green;
  padding:10px
}
.flex-container > div {
 background:silver;
 padding:10px;
}
@media print {
    .flex-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
      overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have a .outer-container element on my dom.

Comment: No. This was an example, as you have not provided any context in your demo. You said your issue was with the text being inside of other elements. My outer container is meant to represent your other elements, which you have to style in the media query.

Comment: @Mizlul You said that the problem is not present if you put your demo in its own file and display that directly. That means the problem is not in your demo at all. Then you said it occurs when "with a div in some web app" that I don't know anything about so I just created a div to represent your "some web app".

Comment: @Mizlul I have updated my answer, now it does not include any other selectors. Though I can not know if this will work in your situation.

Comment: that's right, if I run the demo separately it shows perfectly fine, but if I integrate it into some other webapp then it doesnt work properly, so looks like something on the web app is overriding the behaviour of this print preview or i dont know exactly i should probably spend more time investigating this.

Comment: i don't know if I have to make a separate question on why this demo working fine on its own, but when integrating to some other web apps the print preview no longer works as it works the demo on its own. For me I could not find anything what is it causing the issue that it is not behaving correctly when integrating some other web app.

Comment: for instance if you pase the demo code into this editor: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox the print preview wont behave the same way, so the text gets cuts off.